# Best VPS performance 1024 mb RAM on HDD or 512mb on SSD

Tags: memory, performance, ssd, vps

I'm currently running 4 small websites on different cheap shared hosting providers and I'm looking for a different solution. I might put them on one single VPS. The shared hosting only offers 60mb memory and I need a small speed upgrade. I've got two choices, but more exact details are not available. Both use 1 Xeon core.

1. 1024 MB memory on HDD
2. 512 MB memory on SSD

According to the 2nd option their set-up is faster due to the use of ssd's. Could that actually be true?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, 60 MB is next to nothing! With the option of server hard drives, remember that their "regular" HDDs are server grade - meaning they're extremely fast already. Would an SSD be faster? Yes, a little bit. If it were my choice, I'd go with more memory. That will future-proof you should you want to do more with your VPS.